# Converting from Data to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to Convert the data that searched into a model since it split because I'm using repository pattern.
this is my code:

```
 public List<Supplier> Find(string name)
        {
            using (var suppre = new SupplierRepository())
            {
                return suppre.Find(x => x.Supplier_Name == name).ToList().Select(x => new SupplierView()
                {
                    Supplier_Id = x.Supplier_Id,
                    Supplier_Name = x.Supplier_Name,
                    Supplier_Address = x.Supplier_Address,
                    Email = x.Email,
                    Contact_No = x.Contact_No,
                    Contact_Person = x.Contact_Person,
                    Type_of_medicine = x.Type_of_medicine,
                    Product_ID = x.Product_ID
                });
            }
        }
```

and it gives me an error saying:

> Cannot convert expression type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Dept.Model.SupplierModel>` to return type `System.Collections.Generic.List<Dept.Data.Supplier>`

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature is expecting to return a

```
 List<Supplier>
```

but your actual return statement from your linq select is returning a

```
 List<SupplierView>
```

you may simply need to change your return type to be

```
 List<SupplierView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I applaud your use of separate data models from edit models.  I would recommend using a tool like AutoMapper to make some of this a lot easier (and automatic).

With automapper your method would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SupplierView> Find(string name)
{
    using (var suppre = new SupplierRepository())
    {

        return suppre
            .Where(x => x.Supplier_Name == name)
            .Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SupplierView>(x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @mreyeros said, you will also need to move your `ToList` as `Select` returns a `IEnumerable`.

```
    public List<SupplierView> Find(string name)
    {
        using (var suppre = new SupplierRepository())
        {
            return suppre.Find(x => x.Supplier_Name == name).Select(x => new SupplierView()
            {
                Supplier_Id = x.Supplier_Id,
                Supplier_Name = x.Supplier_Name,
                Supplier_Address = x.Supplier_Address,
                Email = x.Email,
                Contact_No = x.Contact_No,
                Contact_Person = x.Contact_Person,
                Type_of_medicine = x.Type_of_medicine,
                Product_ID = x.Product_ID
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public List<SupplierView> Find(string name)
    {
        using (var suppre = new SupplierRepository())
        {
            return suppre.Find(x => x.Supplier_Name == name).Select(x => new SupplierView()
            {
                Supplier_Id = x.Supplier_Id,
                Supplier_Name = x.Supplier_Name,
                Supplier_Address = x.Supplier_Address,
                Email = x.Email,
                Contact_No = x.Contact_No,
                Contact_Person = x.Contact_Person,
                Type_of_medicine = x.Type_of_medicine,
                Product_ID = x.Product_ID
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

the reason why it gave you an error was because your method signature stated you returning a List which is your data and you first have to do Select which is conversion statement before you return it to list.